# Need to allow space at first position in bootstrap tagsinput

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, space, bootstrap-tags-input

I need to allow space at first position in bootstrap **tagsinput**. 
Need Resulted Tag Like this:  **" Tag"** not like **"Tag"** that.

I have tried Trim (methods: false) and it is working fine for tag's post space but not working for tag's pre space.

Please suggest as soon as possible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leading white space is there, is just not shown by the browser. You can check this with an inspector. Adding the CSS declaration for the class that renders the labels, should solve the problem and show the leading white spaces.

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: Yes, Its working fine, Thanks Man.                                                                  Yes trimming space is browser default behavior and it prevented by using "white-space: pre" property of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Just append a space to the first string in your array

```
data[0].text = ' ' + data[0].text;
```

if `text` is your label field.

Comment: Thanks Svarog for quick response but in this tagsinput user type manually, and some time user entering pre-space and some time not So this fix not work for me.

Comment: so you only want 1 space as your prefix in any condition ?! what about `data[0].text = ' ' + data[0].text.trim();`

Comment: Thanks Man for quick reply. Found solution i just need to add one CSS property :   white-space: pre.